# SQL check if first value in line is number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql, definition-query, arcgis-10.4

In the layer definition query in ArcGIS 10.4 I want to only use objects that look like

```
1/12 Main Street
12-2 Side Street
etc
```

and not ones that have

```
Main Street
Side Street
```

Is this possible?

So something like

```sql
Select *.FROM DCDB WHERE

    Address.startswith[0..9]
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, should work now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like `ISNUMERIC(LEFT(ADDRESS,1)) = 1` should give you the result you're after.

**EDIT #1** Well that doesn't seem to work in ArcGIS, but this should:

```
ADDRESS LIKE '1%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '2%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '3%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '4%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '5%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '6%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '7%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '8%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '9%' 
OR ADDRESS LIKE '0%'
```

**EDIT #2**  This is what I was after:

```
SUBSTRING(ADDRESS,1,1) <= '9'
```

Which finds whether the first character of the value is less than or equal to 9 (which will give any number and exclude any text).  Since it is a Text field you have to include the single quotes around the value `'9'`.

Comment: maybe not... I'll look at it further

Comment: yup, it got rid of everything.

Comment: Brilliant. I was to fixated with arrays. This is a great hack.

Comment: Been playing with this a bit - seems you can also use letters as well as numbers.  `SUBSTRING(ADDRESS, 1, 1) < 'G'` will find all numbers and any letter from A to F. Can filter out the numbers too with a `> '9'`

Comment: The reason ISNUMERIC doesn't work in Arc is because it is Transact SQL (SQL server) and Arc uses vanilla SQL.